# do ISPs implement security measures?

Tags: brute-force, denial-of-service

For example, if a user is receiving a denial of service attack, with huge amounts of packets being sent to him to disrupt his service, will the ISP notice and stop the offending traffic?

Another example, if someone has an internet-facing VNC server and a bad guy is trying to bruteforce the password with tons of login attempts, will the ISP notice and stop the attempts?

In the answers I would like to know if it would be possible/practical/likely for ISPs to implement these things, and why.

Answer (score 4):

Denial of service attacks and brute force attacks on a single client are two very different things and ISPs will have different responses. Also, ISPs are not all created equal, some will be better than others at detecting and dealing with problems.

Distributed denial of service attacks attempt to flood a host or hosts with malicious traffic of some kind, and this will impact the service an ISP will be able to offer their customers as all this traffic must go through the ISP's network devices. Good ISPs will monitor their traffic levels and analyze it when certain thresholds are passed, and good ones will also have trained their staff to respond. All ISPs can run at least some filtering to reduce the levels of unwanted traffic. They'll do this to protect their own network as much as their customers.

ISPs do not typically monitor for malicious traffic like brute force cracking, although some services may offer that type of service as an extra. Many ISPs have the technology in place to monitor for that type of traffic, however it would cost them time and money to do it so they won't unless they have a financial incentive.

Comment: so basically a bad guy could be running an automated password cracking tool against a VNC or RDP service 24 hours a day, 7 days a week uninterruptedly, unless the VNC or RDP end user has some sort of defense against it?

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the ISP and their level of customer care/repsonsibility. As a business ISP we consider any routers/firewalls/etc we provide as our responsibility; we don't expect every small to medium enterprise to have a technical team or someone competent enough to be able to protect themselves proactively so we will deal with these as and when we are notified. On NAT connections we will normally enable some sort of Denial of Service protection as part of that router's firewall, if it's not NATed then obviously we configure the firewall to deal with that if we've provided that too.

We do have monitoring tools set up to give us email/text/push notifications for suspected DDoS attacks and we're close enough with our customers to be able to identify if they're the type of customer who would ordinarily be experiencing a high amount of inbound traffic. Generally though we deal with a lot of internal technical teams and what they do with their customers is between them and their customer, what might appear as a malicious DDoS from our perspective could be something they are doing themselves, so we would consult them before ever taking action, thus there are no automated procedures in place upon detection beyond notification.

I should also mention that we keep a very close eye on our lines with regards to performance and our customers expect that, so even if a customer of ours was being DDoS'd in a way that could somehow bypass our notification system, the likelihood is that we would be notified by the customer anyway and we'd quickly realize it as a DDoS and act accordingly where possible.

Regarding VNC: No, that's a very different issue and would have to be raised by the customer themselves if they were able to log the attempts. Once again in that situation it would depend on the hardware/firewall they have available. The short answer is that we don't get alerts like we do for potential DDoS attacks but we'll always do what we can to mitigate the problem.

Comment: so basically a bad guy could be running an automated password cracking tool against a VNC or RDP service 24 hours a day, 7 days a week uninterruptedly, unless the VNC or RDP end user has some sort of defense against it?

Comment: Well yes, this would happen regardless of ISPs being involved though. What you're asking is whether or not your ISP would tell you. The general answer I'd imagine is 'No' unless you've had some kind of prior arrangement to receive an alert regarding this. 

ISP customers (including our own) are using terminal services all the time, we can't really tell/aren't interested in whether or not authentication requests to those services are failing or not. Even if we were monitoring those at router-level, it'd be far too much time wasted trying to chase it up when it could be something innocuous.